# iOS: Address Book

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, addressbookui

Is it possible to select multiple contacts at one time as the Address Book interface appears before it hides? or it should really takes you to select only one contact each time the address book interface appears?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Whatsapp did this.

If you need an example, here's one:

[MultiContactsSelctor](https://github.com/sergiomtzlosa/MultiContactsSelector-ios)

[image]